# Syntax error in tsconfig file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

[image]

Not sure why, but getting a Parsing error in this tsconfig.js file I just created.
Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

Thoughts?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./moonholdings/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "./app/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file extension should be `.json`, not `.js`.

Comment: Ah thanks, however after changing it to json correctly, still getting that error. Actually more... ah had to restart! thanks 6mins...